How to fix netplan error on Rocky 9.4 FileNotFoundError
I am running Rocky 9.4 and installed netplan by:
sudo dnf install netplan

Before making any changes, the ip address via dhcp is 192.168.0.102 and the ethernet name is enp0s3.
I created file /etc/netplan/static.yaml like this:
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.107/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1

If I run netplan get I see this, which looks ok:
netplan get
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - "192.168.0.107/24"
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      routes:
      - to: "default"
        via: "192.168.0.1"

But the problem is with the apply:
sudo netplan --debug >~/applystdout.txt 2>~/applystderr.txt

I separated out the std error:
DEBUG:no netplan generated networkd configuration exists
DEBUG:netplan generated NM configuration changed, restarting NM
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp0s3
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/netplan", line 23, in <module>
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 231, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 61, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 231, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 284, in command_apply
    for iface in utils.nm_interfaces(restart_nm_glob, devices):
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 70, in nm_interfaces
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/run/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-enp0s3.nmconnection'

Debug messaging to stdout:
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.787: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.787: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: enp0s3: adding new route
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: enp0s3: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: Generating output files..
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: networkd: definition enp0s3 is not for us (backend 2)
** (generate:1562): DEBUG: 16:02:18.788: openvswitch: definition enp0s3 is not for us (backend 2)
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.140: starting new processing pass
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.140: starting new processing pass
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.141: enp0s3: adding new route
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.141: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.141: enp0s3: setting default backend to 2
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.141: Configuration is valid
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.262: starting new processing pass
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.262: starting new processing pass
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.262: enp0s3: adding new route
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: enp0s3: setting default backend to 2
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: Configuration is valid
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: starting new processing pass
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: starting new processing pass
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: enp0s3: adding new route
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: enp0s3: setting default backend to 2
** (process:1560): DEBUG: 16:02:19.263: Configuration is valid

Why the FileNotFoundError and why no /run/NetworkManager/xxx file???
How do I fix this?
...
New test.
I found another static adddress example online at : https://gal.vin/posts/2023/ubuntu-static-ip/
So I tried:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.105/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.168.4.100,194.168.8.100]      
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1

But this time error was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/netplan", line 23, in <module>
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 231, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 61, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 231, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 271, in command_apply
    utils.networkctl_reload()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 111, in networkctl_reload
    subprocess.check_call(['networkctl', 'reload'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1837, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'networkctl'

